# QGIS: OSM Landscape layer not printed

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am new in GIS and I am trying to print a new map. If I use Google Street and web layer, it got printed without problem in the composer, but OSM Landscape does not appear on the printed document (it does on the screen though).

Any clue?

PS: I am using QGIS 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits:
QGIS version    2.4.0-Chugiak   QGIS code revision  exported
Compiled against Qt 4.8.6   Running against Qt  4.8.6
Compiled against GDAL/OGR   1.10.1  Running against GDAL/OGR    1.10.1
Compiled against GEOS   3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2    Running against GEOS    3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
PostgreSQL Client Version   9.3.4   SpatiaLite Version  4.1.1
QWT Version 5.2.3   PROJ.4 Version  480
QScintilla2 Version

Comment: It's been mentioned in a few similar questions -- the OpenLayers plugin isn't compatible with composers in QGIS. It's only designed for use in the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading that OSM-based layers will print in QGIS at pre-defined scales (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels). Related to QGIS issue http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827.

Comment: Dear mbacou,Thanks for the reply. I had seen the post you refer on hub.qgis.org. However, in my case, the problem is not that the tiles are not aligned, but that they are not printed at all... I will try on a Windows machine to check if it is specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried to do this recently, but in the past (6 months ago) the creation of a printed map using composer and the Openlayers plugin with some (all?) of the available OSM layers often didn't work for me. The other problem was that the only way I could find to set the choice of zoom level that the printed map used was to alter the resolution in the composer. In the end, for printing one-off maps of a small area (e.g. a city), I found a much better solution. There's a web service called [Bigmap](http://bigmap.osmz.ru/) (there may be others) with which you can download a single zoom level of map tiles covering a decent enough area to allow for one-off printed maps. Bigmap stitches the tiles together, and you can download a '.map' file alongside the resulting png file. Open the .map file in QGIS (as a raster layer), and this provides the georeference which will bring in the png image in the correct place.

The interface on Bigmap is a little confusing, but persevere. You're choosing the map source first. Then you move in and out on the zoom levels - the options here are to account for the fact that you may want to zoom in and out changing the map area, or in and out a zoom level while maintaining the same area. 'Enqueue' asks the service to process your request, and after a while you'll get to download the result. Watch for the 'enqueue' link greying out - this happens if you have too many tiles selected.

I've sometimes needed to ask for two or three downloads for something I'm printing - but the georeference of course means that these sit nicely next to each other.

I added some slightly clearer instructions (I hope) a few months ago within the relevant [OSM wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap) here.